# how to plot multiple time series in chartjs where each time series has different times

Tags: javascript, python, chart.js

I have two time series for example:

```
s1:
  2017-01-06 18:39:30    100
  2017-01-07 18:39:28    101
```

and

```
s2:
2017-01-07 18:00:00     90
2017-01-08 18:00:00    105
```

I want to plot these in a Chartjs chart, however it seems that Chartjs only takes one x-axis array (or label in Chartjs terminology).

**So my question is what is the best way to plot both of these?**

My approach was to write a function (in python, although the language doesn't really matter for this part) that iterates through both time series and creates 3 new arrays which is in the format apparently Chartjs needs based off the 1st example here: https://www.sitepoint.com/introduction-chart-js-2-0-six-examples/

The algorithm (in sudo code) goes like:

```
    # inputs are initial time series s1 and s2
    y1 = [] # to hold new s1 data values
    y2 = [] # to hold new s2 data values
    x  = [] # to hold times

    # iterate through longest series s1 or s2
    if s1[idx].time > s2[idx].time
      x.append(s1[idx].time)
      y1.append(s1[idx].data)
      # y2 appends the linear interpolation of 
      # of closest y2 points

    if (s1[idx].time < s2[idx].time)
      x.append(s2[idx].time)
      # opposite of above. ie. swap y1<->y2, s1->s2

    else # they have the same time
      x.append(s1[idx].time)
      y1.append(s1[idx].data)
      y2.append(s2[idx].data)
```

There are a couple other conditional checks for when data runs out of the shorter series but that is the main logic. After which I have 3 arrays that I can now add to chart js via one time/label array/x-axis and two data arrays. However this seems WAY more complicated than it should be considering how common I assume this use case is. Any help or advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not quite getting what you want, can you provide a simple mock up image of what you want to achieve?

Comment: So just as a clarifying comment to others, My main mistake was using labels instead of the x:some-time, y:data format, plus the time scales option suggested by Waterscroll. That might not be overly obvious from my initial post.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In ChartJS, label is a [Category Cartesian Axis](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/category.html). Since you mentioned linear interpolation in your code, I assume the strings like `2017-01-06 18:39:30` are not categories, they represent the numeric values of the x-axis. So we need to inform ChartJS that the strings in the x axis are actually time. We do this in the scale options.

```js
var s1 = {
  label: 's1',
  borderColor: 'blue',
  data: [
    { x: '2017-01-06 18:39:30', y: 100 },
    { x: '2017-01-07 18:39:28', y: 101 },
  ]
};

var s2 = {
  label: 's2',
  borderColor: 'red',
  data: [
    { x: '2017-01-07 18:00:00', y: 90 },
    { x: '2017-01-08 18:00:00', y: 105 },
  ]
};

var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: { datasets: [s1, s2] },
  options: {
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        type: 'time'
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.1/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
```

You can find more information in [Chart.js documentation](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/).

Comment: I was trying to get this code to work and it didn't until I realized, I needed to load `Moment.js` to handle the dates given as strings. I hope this saves someone else's time.

Comment: @CGFoX you saved my life, thank you. I've been messing with it for the last hour

Answer (score 4):

You can have data of the form [{x:"value", y:"value"}] when your graph is of type [scatter](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/scatter.html).

So to make your graph work, do this.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("graph");
var s1 = [{x:"2017-01-06 18:39:30",y:"100"},{x:"2017-01-07 18:39:28",y:"101"}];
var s2 = [{x:"2017-01-07 18:00:00",y:"90"},{x:"2017-01-08 18:00:00",y:"105"}];

var graphParams = {
 type:"scatter",
 data:{
  datasets: [{
   label:"Series 1",
   data:s1,
   borderColor:"red",
   backgroundColor:"transparent",
  },
  {
   label:"Series 2",
   data:s2,
   borderColor:"blue",
   backgroundColor:"transparent",
  }],
 },
 options:{
  maintainAspectRatio:false,
  responsive:false, 
  scales:{
   xAxes:[{
    type:"time",
    distribution: "series",
   }],
  }
 }

}
ctx = new Chart(canvas, graphParams);
```

```html
<canvas id="graph" height="500" width="700"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.2.1/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is basically it. I was trying to get it to work with 2.7.1, but Waterscroll's solution seems to work as is.