# How to create multiple y-axis time series chart

Tags: django, d3.js, charts, chart.js, canvasjs

I am trying to map multiple charts where x-axis (`time`) is fixed but y-axis can take multiple values like CPU%, RAM, IO-RATE and so on. If I try to build individual graphs things seems pretty easy but I have this weird requirement where I need to map everything on to same chart. I have been trying out things with `chartjs` library and I could see that [Cartesian axes](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/) is capable of handling multiple axes. But the examples I find around `Cartesian` mostly have x-axis with some fixed label values. In my case it's time and I wonder how to do the same for **time series**. I also found this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48143233/how-to-plot-multiple-time-series-in-chartjs-where-each-time-series-has-different) for `multiple time series` but that doesn't seem to create multiple y-axis. What is required is something like [this](https://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/how-to/multiple-y-axis/) but I am having hard time trying to figure out how to achieve this.

I am using `django` for backend and I am open to try out any library out there that does this and can easily integrate with `django`. Currently I have been exploring things with `chartjs`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to define a unique `xAxis` and define it as a [time cartesian axis](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html).

```
xAxes: [{
  type: 'time',
  time: {
    unit: 'minute',
    tooltipFormat: 'HH:mm:ss'
  }
}],
```

Then you define a [linear cartesian](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/linear.html) `yAxis` for each `dataset` and make sure, the value of the `yAxis.id` matches the corresponding `dataset.yAxisID`. Use 'yAxis.position' to define whether the axis shall appear `left` or `right` of the chart.

Optionally you may also define the following [Plugin Core API](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/plugins.html#plugin-core-api) `beforeLayout` function that makes sure that an `yAxis` is also hidden when it's data set is hidden through a mouse click on a legend label.

```
plugins: [{
    beforeLayout: chart => chart.data.datasets.forEach((ds, i) => chart.config.options.scales.yAxes[i].display = !ds._meta[0].hidden)
  }],
```

Please have a look at below runnable code snippet that illustrates how it can be done.

```js
const now = new Date().getTime();
const timestamps = new Array(10).fill().map((v, i) => now - i * 60000).reverse();

new Chart('chart', {
  type: 'line',
  plugins: [{
    beforeLayout: chart => chart.data.datasets.forEach((ds, i) => chart.config.options.scales.yAxes[i].display = !ds._meta[0].hidden)
  }],
  data: {
    labels: timestamps,
    datasets: [{
        label: 'CPU',
        yAxisID: 'yAxis-CPU',
        data: [68, 70, 71, 72, 75, 75, 76, 77, 79, 76],
        borderColor: 'red',
        fill: false
      },
      {
        label: 'RAM',
        yAxisID: 'yAxis-RAM',
        data: [22, 23, 23, 23, 22, 20, 22, 22, 23, 25],
        borderColor: 'blue',
        fill: false
      },
      {
        label: 'IO-RATE',
        yAxisID: 'yAxis-IO-RATE',
        data: [0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.8, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2],
        borderColor: 'green',
        fill: false
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        type: 'time',
        time: {
          unit: 'minute',
          displayFormats: {
            minute: 'HH:mm'
          },
          tooltipFormat: 'HH:mm:ss'
        }
      }],
      yAxes: [{
          id: 'yAxis-CPU',
          type: 'linear',
          position: 'left',
          scaleLabel: {
            display: true,
            labelString: 'CPU %'
          },
          gridLines : {
            display: false
          },
          ticks: {
            beginAtZero: true
          }
        },
        {
          id: 'yAxis-RAM',
          type: 'linear',
          position: 'left',
          scaleLabel: {
            display: true,
            labelString: 'RAM %'
          },
          gridLines : {
            display: false
          },
          ticks: {
            beginAtZero: true
          }
        },
        {
          id: 'yAxis-IO-RATE',
          type: 'linear',
          position: 'right',
          scaleLabel: {
            display: true,
            labelString: 'IO-Rate %'
          },
          gridLines : {
            display: false
          },
          ticks: {
            beginAtZero: true
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="chart" height="90"></canvas>
```

Comment: Many Thanks. Precisely what I was looking out for. What if I have situation where x-axis time frame might be varying for each data set. Say everything starts at a particular time but some of the data capture would end long before the next thing ends. Any suggestions on how to handle that.

Comment: @chidori: In such cases, you omit `data.labels` but define the `data` as individual points as explained here https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html#input-data

Comment: This is just what I need! One thing - what's the easiest way to hide axis when a dataset is hidden (by clicking on it) ?

Comment: @Njål Arne Gjermundshaug: Please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/61854730/2358409, it illustrates how to hide/show individual axes depending whether corresponding datasets are hidden or not.

Comment: Actually - your example works perfectly... I was looking at my own code and I had accidentally commented our a line. Again - thanks for your code snippet!! 

Comment: I got a small hack while `plt.plot(timestamp, value)` add new line `plt.legend()` it separate each of the plot.